# jQuery UI Autocomplete: как при клике на подсказку выполнить поиск?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[name="keyword"]').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { query: request.term },
    url: '/ajax.php',
    success: function(data){
     response($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   });
  },
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 2
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="input-lg" name="keyword" autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit">ПОИСК</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил `change` на `select`. Такой вариант работает:

```
$('input[name="keyword"]').autocomplete({

    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $('input[name="keyword"]').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#search').submit(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

В jquery UI Autocomplete есть событие `select`, которое сработает при выборе подсказки - http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Только `input` и `button` в `<form></form>` заключить

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[name="keyword"]').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { query: request.term },
    url: '/ajax.php',
    success: function(data){
     response($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   });
  },
  delay: 500,
  minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#search').submit();
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="search" id="search" meyhod="post">
<input type="text" class="input-lg" name="keyword" autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit">ПОИСК</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: При таком варианте получается со второго клика: выбираю подсказку(поиск не идет), после этого при клике по любой области экрана выполняется поиск.

Comment: @jazzfriends да, всё верно, это я перепутал, событие `change` срабатывает при потере фокуса полем, а `select` при выборе из списка